# Open Graph Beta: can it be used with Facebook iFrame Canvas application

Tags: facebook, facebook-iframe, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps

Playing around with Open Graph Beta I realized that the Open Graph is created for webpages outside of facebook.com. While trying to publish an action and an object I realized that an object should be defined on a webpage outside of Facebook.com.

And it looks that inside Facebook.com I cannot create objects. e.g. http://apps.faceobook.com/myNamespace/objects/car?id=102 throws me an error

Is this intended?

> (OAuthException) (#3502) Object at URL
>   http://apps.facebook.com/myNamespace/objects/car has og:type of
>   'game'. The property 'car' requires an object of og:type
>   'myNamespace:car'.

I set the og:type inside the iFrame app to

```
<meta property="og:type" content="myNamespace:car"/>
```

but the error persists.

Comment: It looks like this related to Facebook's bug with OG metadata http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/290792740949892

Comment: Thanks Juicy. It looks to be similar - OG:type is ignored in an iFrame app. Thank you. I subscribed to this bug.

Answer (score 0):

[The bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/290792740949892) has been fixed now.

> Fixed the scraper to transform canvas app URLs into the appropriate
>   iframe URL. Note that we stop following any further redirects after
>   doing such a transformation.